Is it possible to make a 3-min rail connection in Limerick?
I want to go from Ennis, Ireland to Dublin after 7 pm on a Thursday.
Irish Rail gives an option on their planner (timetable, page 12, Monday to Saturday) at Limerick Colbert as follows:
19:11 Ennis
19:52 Limerick Colbert
=====
19:55 Limerick Colbert
20:23 Limerick Junction

Is that transfer even possible? The timetable makes it seem like it's the same train but I am not sure.

Why include the entire timetable? It's tldr; to find your train. Which page is the train on? What day of the week? I can't even find a time of  19:52 by skimming through it.

@WeatherVane Only non-stale way of reference, edited the info

You may want to check the live station departures for Limerick tomorrow a bit before that time, you’ll see the services going through. Some of them are indeed the same train just stopping through (and changing direction, given the station layout), but it’s too late now to see that specific train.

It's not unsusual to delay a departure by a few minutes if it's a 'connection'. In UK, that would have to be within the limits where the rail regulator imposes a fine on the train operator for late running.

The Google Maps Street View pictures inside the station make it look like all trains to/from Ennis and Dublin use platforms 1 and 2 (most often just platform 1, so the same train). So either same train or cross-platform. But check the live departures tomorrow for confirmation.

Irish Rail is highly unreliable, so unless it's officially a connecting train and will wait, there's no guarantee of making the connection.

@Mohirl Looking at the official >10min delay reports on the Limerick to Galway line, being sth like 95% (of trains on time) average is very good compared to something like the Deutsche Bahn which hover over 65% for their long distance trips

It may well be the same train but even if it’s not, I think it will be intended to connect. Limerick is a small station with only about 4 platforms. You might get a cross platform transfer but even if you have to go to another one, it won’t take long.

Note that’s it’s a terminal station, so by being ready at the front of the train you are guaranteed to have a very short distance to the other platform, if it’s not the same platform or the same train.

The Iarnrod Eireann website shows that Ennis to Limerick Junction journey as having a change of train. But it is shown as a through journey so I think it is likely the 2nd train will wait for the first at Limerick.
https://www.irishrail.ie/en-ie/Home
